# Is there a way to order by the values in a specific column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

SQL Server 2008

```
(select case 
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate) <datepart(month, getdate()) 
then 'Expired'
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)=datepart(month, getdate())
then 'Requal required by end of this month'
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)-1=datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 'Requal required by end of next month'
when datepart(m, enrollments.enddate) >datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 'Current'
Else null
End) as [Certification Status], Enrollments.CurrentGrade Grade, 
students.Status [Associate Status]

from venrollmentsfilter enrollments
left join students on enrollments.studentindex = students.studentindex  left join affiliations on students.affiliationindex = affiliations.affiliationindex  left join schools on students.schoolindex = schools.schoolindex  left join programs on students.programindex = programs.programindex  left join sections on enrollments.sectionindex = sections.sectionindex  left join courses on sections.courseindex = courses.courseindex  left join teachers on sections.teacherindex = teachers.teacherindex  left join lmsterms on sections.lmstermindex = lmsterms.lmstermindex  left join semesters on lmsterms.semesterindex = semesters.semesterindex  left join catalogs on courses.catalogindex = catalogs.catalogindex  left join departments on courses.departmentindex = departments.departmentindex  left join studentregionlist on students.studentregionlistindex = studentregionlist.studentregionlistindex  

WHERE  Enrollments.Status  = 'active'  AND  Sections.Name  like '%Medical Requalification - q1%'  and datepart(year, enrollments.enddate) = datepart(yyyy, getdate()) 
order by [Certification Status]
```

**I want to order the values from the Certification Status column as follows Expired, Requal required by the end of this month, Requal required by the end of next month, Current.**

[image: Table values]

Answer (score 1):

You use a `CASE` on the `ORDER BY`

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Expired' 
                  THEN 1
              WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Requal required by the end of this month' 
                  THEN 2
              WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Requal required by the end of next month' 
                  THEN 3
              WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Current' 
                  THEN 4
         END
```

**EDIT** you need put your query as a sub query because you are creating a column alias. Then you can use the alias in the outside query with the `order by`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       <YourQuery>
      ) as T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Expired' 
                  THEN 1
              WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Requal required by the end of this month' 
                  THEN 2
              WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Requal required by the end of next month' 
                  THEN 3
              WHEN [Certification Status] = 'Current' 
                  THEN 4
         END
```

Comment: Error message: Invalid Column name 'Certification Status'

Answer (score 0):

Add another column in the select query that would have numeric values (call it Certification Status Priority for instance), and order by that field. I am including a high level picture here (you may have to include the base query inside an inner query and add the order by outside)

```
(select case 
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate) <datepart(month, getdate()) 
then 'Expired'
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)=datepart(month, getdate())
then 'Requal required by end of this month'
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)-1=datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 'Requal required by end of next month'
when datepart(m, enrollments.enddate) >datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 'Current'
Else null
End) as [Certification Status],

select case 
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate) <datepart(month, getdate()) 
then 4
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)=datepart(month, getdate())
then 3
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)-1=datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 2
when datepart(m, enrollments.enddate) >datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 1
Else null
End) as [Certification Status Priority],

Enrollments.CurrentGrade Grade, 
students.Status [Associate Status]

from venrollmentsfilter enrollments
left join students on enrollments.studentindex = students.studentindex  
left join affiliations on students.affiliationindex = affiliations.affiliationindex  
left join schools on students.schoolindex = schools.schoolindex  
left join programs on students.programindex = programs.programindex  
left join sections on enrollments.sectionindex = sections.sectionindex  
left join courses on sections.courseindex = courses.courseindex  
left join teachers on sections.teacherindex = teachers.teacherindex  
left join lmsterms on sections.lmstermindex = lmsterms.lmstermindex  
left join semesters on lmsterms.semesterindex = semesters.semesterindex  
left join catalogs on courses.catalogindex = catalogs.catalogindex  
left join departments on courses.departmentindex = departments.departmentindex  
left join studentregionlist on students.studentregionlistindex = studentregionlist.studentregionlistindex  

WHERE  Enrollments.Status  = 'active'  AND  Sections.Name  like '%Medical Requalification - q1%'  and datepart(year, enrollments.enddate) = datepart(yyyy, getdate()) 
order by case 
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate) <datepart(month, getdate()) 
then 4
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)=datepart(month, getdate())
then 3
when datepart(month, enrollments.enddate)-1=datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 2
when datepart(m, enrollments.enddate) >datepart(m, getdate()) 
then 1
Else null
End
```

Comment: That worked. Any way not to have the additional column "Certification Status Priority" visible in the results?

Comment: you can wrap the whole query inside another select where you only include the columns you need(not including the priority field). But then again, the ordering may be lost ! I believe you would need to keep the field in the select if you need it ordered by it.

Comment: Thanks. It wouldn't be too bad to keep it afterall. Really appreciate the help!